# Socket.io disconnect not working from componentwillunmount

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets

I am trying to create a real time chat using socket.io. However, I am having trouble disconnecting my chat application.

Front end

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state={
                endpoint: 'localhost:3001'
        }
        this.socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.socket.emit('join', {name: "name",room: "rooms" }, () => {

        });
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.socket.emit('disconnect');
        this.socket.off();
    }
```

Server side

```
var app = express();
let server = app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT));
let io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('We have a new conneciton');

    socket.on('join', ({name, room}, callback) => {
        console.log(name, room);

    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user had left');
    })
})
```

The user had left doesn't popup in the console when the component unmount.

Where did i go wrong?

Also i noticed that the socket  'join' and 'disconnect will always run even though I don't call from the client side. why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `socket.disconnect()` to disconnect from the socket.

> off() does not stop the this client-side socket from receiving any server-sent messages, it just prevents the specified event handler from firing. Usually, the desired.

The `join/disconnect` are default events in socket, The `join` event will always trigger when a client gets connected to the socket and the `disconnect` will always trigger when a client gets disconnected. That's why you see these event in logs even you are not calling these explicitly, these events will called automatically.

Try the below code to disconnect from socket connection.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        endpoint: 'localhost:3001'
    }
    this.socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.socket.emit('join', { name: "name", room: "rooms" }, () => {
    });
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.socket.emit('disconnect');
    socket.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: ahh got it! Thank you sir